# Issues using DisplayLink on Manjaro Linux

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, displaylink

I am having troubles setting a DisplayLink on my two monitors with my computer.

I am running Manjaro i3 edition with Linux 52 on a ThinkPadT460.

I went through this set of instructions:

```bash
yay -S linux52-headers
reboot
yay -S evdi displaylink
reboot
sudo nano /usr/shar/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-displaylink.conf
Section "Device"
   Identifer "DisplayLink"
  Driver "modesetting"
  Option "Pagelip" "false"
EndSection
sudo nano /usr/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-evdidevice.conf
Section "OutputClass"
  Identifier "DisplayLink"
  MatchDriver "evdi"
  Driver "modesetting"
  Option "AccelMethod" "none"
EndSection
reboot
systemctl start displaylink
systemctl enable displaylink
reboot
```

The problem being that even so:

```bash
xrandr --listproviders
```

Only gives me one display.

Comment: DisplayLink support for the Linux environment sucks. I'm having exactly the same problem. I had the same problem on Ubuntu before.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> Identif**i**er "DisplayLink"
>
> !Option "Page**F**lip" "false"

You have an `i` and a `F` missing!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to install displaylink on any arch like system is to install it from AUR. Currently evdi 1.8 is not supported, so make sure you will pick version 1.7.x. You will be prompted to select the evdi version, when installing displaylink via yay. If you download and compile it manually then versions 1.7.1 or 1.7.2 should work.

```
yay displaylink
```

Don't forget to check pacman as your distro might already have it's own packages that can work out of the box.

Check this wiki instructions in case it does not work:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DisplayLink

Especially check if following config was created, so that your Xorg can recognize the new display and check if displaylink.service is running:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-evdidevice.conf
```

Also check your dmesg and journalctl for any possible USB device errors.

If you still cannot make it work, check if your device is really displaylink compatible. There are devices with Sillicon motion chip that are different than displaylink technology. Also look at the evdi github issues pages and readme. You can get some good advice there: https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues

Answer (score 0):

I'm using DisplayLink on Manjaro and most of the time, it breaks because of kernel upgrade, you have to rebuild your AUR every time you upgrade the ( major version of?) kernel.

See the list of Aur package I'm using to make it working, with no additional configuration:

```
$ pacman -Q |grep -e "evdi" -e "displaylink"
displaylink 5.7-1
displaylink-connect 3.3.0-1
evdi-compat-git 1.14.03.r0.g19476e7-1
```

So install these 3 modules and make sure to rebuild them after your kernel upgrades.

I'm using the GUI of pamac manager for the "rebuild" : [image: pamac-manager build]

Answer (score 0):

What does it work for me :

```bash
uname -a
Linux Albert 5.10.199-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 25 10:47:09 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux
pamac install evdi-git
pamac install displaylink
systemctl enable displaylink.service
reboot
```